# Getting Undefined factory elasticsearch7 in magento 2.4.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have migrated magento 2.3.6 version to 2.4.2-p1. But in product listing page I am getting below error.

Exception #0 (DomainException): Undefined factory elasticsearch7

Can someone help me for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you previously use ElasticSearch on Magento 2.3.6? Could it be the value in in core_config_data for ElasticSearch has changed

Comment: No @elfling in 2.3.6 it was mysql. Now in 2.4.2 it's required to have elasticsearch as search engine so have changed it to elasticsearch 7 in db.

Comment: So value in DB is - elasticsearch7 
Then you did bin/magento c:f to pick up new DB value?

Comment: Yes and s:up also. And have also configured server host and port. Also checked connection from backend it is showing successful. But somehow when I am opening product listing page it is throwing this error.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below dev docs steps...
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/elasticsearch/configure-magento.html
Hope it will work.....